# The Charts on the Projective Space of a Real Vector Space

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $V$ be an $n+1$-dimensional normed real vector space. We define $P(V)$ as the topological space $(V-\{0\})/\sim$ where $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $V-\{0\}$ which identifies $v$ and $tv$ for each $v\in V-\{0\}$ and $t\in \mathbf R-\{0\}$.

> I want to show that $P(V)$ is a topological $n$-manifold.

One way I tried how to do it is by taking an $n$-dimensional subspace $U_n$ and a $1$ dimensional subspace $U_1$ of $V$ as define $\varphi:V-U_n\to U_n$ as $\varphi(v)=p(v/\|v\|)$, where $p$ is the projection on $U_n$ with respect to $U_1$. But this doesn't even respect the equivalence relation $\sim$.

Of course, another way to do this would to take a linear isomorphism of $V$ with $\mathbf R^{n+1}$ then then use the charts on $\mathbf R\mathbf P^n$ to construct charts on $P(V)$.

I want to do it in an intrinsic manner---without making any reference to $\mathbf R^{n+1}$, with my main motivation being to understand tha Grassmannians better.

Can somebody help me with these charts?

Thanks.

Comment: There is a small misunderstanding here: do you want to show that it is a topological manifold, or to construct an atlas, or both? To show that it is a manifold you do not need charts.

Comment: For what it's worth: If your eventual aim is to apply a construction to fibres of a vector bundle, it's not necessary to avoid coordinates entirely (a.k.a., to avoid fixing an isomorphism $V \simeq \mathbf{R}^{n+1}$). That is, a construction can be intrinsic even if you _use_ a coordinate system to make the construction. A choice of basis of $V$ identifies $V$ and $\mathbf{R}^{n+1}$ and identifies $G_{k}(V)$ and $G_{k}(\mathbf{R}^{n+1})$. It's enough to show that a change of basis of $V$ induces a diffeomorphism of the Grassmannian $G_{k}(V)$ in a "$GL(V)$-equivariant way".

Comment: @AlexM. As of now I just want to show that $P(V)$ is a topological $n$-manifold. By a chart I just mean a homemorphism of an open set of the domain onto an open subset of a vector space. I don't mean 'smooth chart' when I say chart. The terminology I am using is from Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds(2nd Edition).

Answer (score 4):

The standard charts are $$U_i = \{ [x_1, \dots x_{n+2}] \in \Bbb P (V) \space | \space x_i \neq 0 \} ,$$ with $$h_i : U_i \to \Bbb R ^{n+1}, \space h_i([x_1, \dots, x_{n+2}]) = (\frac {x_1} {x_i}, \dots , \frac {x_{i-1}} {x_i}, \frac {x_{i+1}} {x_i}, \dots, \frac {x_{n+2}} {x_i})$$ for $i=1, \dots, n+2$ (note the "skipped" coordinate). Necessarily they cover $\Bbb P (V)$ since there is no point in it having all projective coordinates $0$. Each of the open charts is thus diffeomorphic (homeomorphic, etc.) to $\Bbb R ^{n+1}$.

**Later edit:**

In order not to explicitly use coordinates, one might mimic the above construction in the following way. Pick $\omega \in V^* \setminus \{0\}$ and let $H _\omega = \ker \space \omega$. Let $\pi : V \to \Bbb P (V), \space \pi(v) = [v]$ be the natural projection. Let $U_\omega = \pi (V \setminus H_\omega)$ and define $h _\omega : U _\omega \to H _\omega, \space h _\omega([v]) = {\rm proj} _{H _\omega} \frac v {\omega(v)}$ (the projection of $\frac v {\omega(v)}$ onto $H _\omega$; this projection is defined by considering the direct sum decomposition $V \simeq H_\omega \oplus {\rm range} \space \omega$). Let us show that $(U_\omega, h_\omega)$ is a chart.

First, note that $\pi ^{-1} (U_\omega) = V \setminus H_\omega$. If this were not true, then you could find $v \in V \setminus H_\omega$ and $h \in H _\omega$ with $\pi (h) = [v]$, but this would mean that $v$ is a non-zero multiple of $h$ and thus belongs to $H_\omega$, which is a contradiction. Therefore, $\pi ^{-1} (U_\omega) = V \setminus H_\omega$ and since $V \setminus H_\omega$ is open, the way topology on $\Bbb P (V)$ is defined (it is the final topology) implies that $U_\omega$ is open too.

Next, note that the fraction $\frac v {\omega(v)}$ onto $H _\omega$ is homogeneous of degree $0$, therefore it only depends on $[v]$, not on $v$, so $h_\omega$ is well-defined. It is continuous, too, as a composition of continuous maps. Bijectivity follows easily. That the inverse is also continuous seems obvious to me, but I find it annoying to write down all the details.

Since $\Bbb P (V) = \bigcup \limits _{\omega \in V^* \setminus \{0\}} U_\omega$, each point of $\Bbb P (V)$ has a local chart of this type around it (and all of them form an atlas, but this too needs checking, that I shall not do).

All this does not prove yet that $\Bbb P (V)$ is a topological manifold, because each $h_\omega$ takes values an a different $H_\omega$. You should finally show that $H_\omega \simeq \Bbb R ^n$ (topologically), but guess what? In order to show that, you will now need to resort to coordinates - but at least this only happens at the very end of the proof! In any case, no proof of what you ask can be completely coordinates-free.

Comment: When we write $[x_1,\ldots, x_{n+1}]\in P(V)$, haven't we implicitly already identified $V$ with $\mathbf R^{n+1}$? My point is, $V$ is not a coordinate space to begin with. It is just a normed vector space. I don't want to use coordinates in $V$ as I mentioned in my post.

Comment: @caffeinemachine: How exactly could one construct a map taking values in $Bbb R ^{n+1}$ "intrinsically", without using coordinates? Everything happening at the most basic level in topology and diffferential geometry must be done in coordinates, and only upon this level can be the subsequent coordinate-free concepts be constructed. Charts and local Euclidianity can only be constructed and tested using coordinates.

Comment: I think it can be done because the Grassmannian $G_k(V)$ of a real vector space can be defined without any reference to coordinates. The charts here will not map into a Euclidean space but rather onto a vector space. And we know that $P(V)$ is just $G_1(V)$. I found the description of the grassmannian rather difficult to follows so I asked this question.

Comment: When you say "is thus diffeomorphic", this "thus" does not seem obvious to me. Don't I need to show that the charts are continuous, etc explicitly?

Comment: @Simoes: Indeed, all those computations must be made. The OP, though, seemed to know enough geometry in order to understand how to do them, I only showed him how to approach the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For each basis $\Gamma = (\lambda_1, \cdots, \lambda_{n+1})$ of the dual space $V^*$ let $W \subset P(V)$ defined by $W := \{ [w] : \lambda_{n+1}(v) \neq 0 \}$. Then $W$ is an open subset of $P(V)$. Declare $x_1 := \frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_{n+1}}, \cdots, x_n := \frac{\lambda_n}{\lambda_{n+1}}$ coordinates  $(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ of $W$. Then it is not difficult to check that coordinates changes are smooth hence $P(V)$ is a topological manifold. \

If you do not want to use basis of the dual space here is a possible solution.
You have to assume that the unit sphere $S:= \{v : \| v \| = 1 \}$ of your normed space is a topological manifold. Then the natural projection $\pi: S \to P(V) $ is a so called double covering hence you can (locally) pull-back charts of $S$ and so obtain that $P(V)$ is a topological manifold.

Comment: Apparently the OP does not want to use bases and coordinates. Otherwise, this is exactly my answer below.

Comment: How do you construct the charts of $S$ without coordinates?

Comment: Induction on the dimension $n$ maybe?. All norms on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ are equivalent. So w.l.o.g. you can assume your norm comes from an inner product. Then once you put coordinates on $S^{n-1}$ you can put coordinates on $S^{n}$ as follows. Fix  any unit vector $u$ and let $u^{\perp}$ its orthogonal complement. Then on the $S^{n-1}$ intersection of $S^n$ and $u^{\perp}$ you have coordinates (by induction). Then a new coordiante $\theta$ is introduced by the formula $\cos(\theta) p + \sin(\theta) u$, where $p \in S^{n-1}$.

Comment: @AlexM. One possible approach is this. Consider a hyperplane  $H$ passing thorough the origin. Then consider the set of points on $S$ which lie on one "side" of $H$. (To define a "side", let's define a relation $\cong$ on $V-H$ as $u\cong v$ if $\{tu+(1-t)v:\ t\in [0, 1]\}$ does not intersect $H$. I am not sure how to show tht $\cong$ is an equivalence relation, but let's say it is) Then pick any one dimensional subspace $U$ of $V$. Let $L$ be a side of $V$. Then I guess $L$ is open in $V$ and we can define $\phi:L\cap S\to H$ as the $\phi(v)$ being the projection of $v$ onto $H$ along $U$.

Comment: @AlexM. I can show that $\cong$, as mentioned in the last comment, is indeed an equivalence relation.

Comment: What are you doing here, if I am not misunderstanding you, is similar as putting coordinates in the unit sphere $S^n$ by means of the stereographic projection. Namely, you have a 1-1 map $\phi$ from $S^n \setminus p$ to the hyperplane $H$ tangent to the point $-p$ and all such maps gave you the atlas since they are compatible.